# Find a finitely generated subgroup of $F_{2}$ of index n, for each $n\geq 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So the hint was: Try to obtain a normal generating set for a kernel in $F_{2}$, then find a way to alter it into a bona fide (finite) generating set.

What is a good way to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1**

> Recall the [Schreier index formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem).

**Hint 2**

> Given $n$, what is the only group of order $n$ (up to isomorphism) whose existence you can be sure of?

**Hint 3**

> Can you obtain a cyclic group of order $n$ as a factor group of $F_{2}$?